# SQL - parametrized procedure with multiple parameters as array

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have very simple procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Report]
@statusValue varchar(200) = '%'
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM SomeTable
WHERE Something LIKE UPPER(@statusValue)
END
```

I'd like to provide user set multiple statusValue. Because there is 6 levels of statusValue in my table, I'd like to provide user to define required statusValue into procedure parameters - something like array.

I don't know, how it exactly works - I'm very new in this area - but I'm supposing to have procedure like this one:

```
EXEC Report @statusValue = 'statusValue1|statusValue2|statusValue3'
```

Do you happen to know, how can I adjust my procedure to have required output. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: create a split function . before  in side sp  store values of parm  in temp table then join temp table  to some table and get you result

Comment: if your project is new and statusvalue cannot be more than 4-5 then you can use bitwise Enum [Flag].Such thing give treamendous boost to performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following user defined function to return values from delimited string (say pipe):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[stringlist_to_table]
    (@list      varchar(8000),
    @delimiter nchar(1) = N',') 
RETURNS @tbl TABLE (value varchar(8000)) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @pos      int,
        @tmpstr   varchar(8000),
        @tmpval   varchar(8000);

    SET @tmpstr = @list;
    SET @pos = charindex(@delimiter , @tmpstr);

    WHILE @pos > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @tmpval = ltrim(rtrim(left(@tmpstr, @pos - 1)))
        INSERT @tbl (value) VALUES(@tmpval)
        SET @tmpstr = substring(@tmpstr, @pos + 1, len(@tmpstr))
        SET @pos = charindex(@delimiter, @tmpstr)
    END

    INSERT @tbl(value) VALUES (ltrim(rtrim(@tmpstr)));
    RETURN
END
```

Now use the following procedure to get the required output:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Report]
    @statusValue varchar(200) = '%'
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @iterator INT = 1;
    DECLARE @total INT = 1;
    DECLARE @keyword VARCHAR(100) = '';

    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY value) SNo, value keyword
    INTO #temp
    FROM dbo.stringlist_to_table(@statusValue, '|')

    SELECT * 
    INTO #output
    FROM SomeTable
    WHERE 1 = 0;

    SELECT @total = MAX(SNo), @iterator = MIN(Sno)
    FROM #temp

    WHILE (@iterator <= @total)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @keyword = '%' + keyword + '%'
        FROM #temp
        WHERE SNo = @iterator;

        INSERT INTO #output
        SELECT * 
        FROM SomeTable
        WHERE Something LIKE @keyword

        SET @iterator = @iterator + 1;
    END

    SELECT *
    FROM #output;

    DROP TABLE #output, #temp;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest way to achieve this is using a custom type. Sample snippet as follows:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.StatusList
AS TABLE
(
  statusValue varchar(200)
);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [Report]
@statusValue AS dbo.StatusList READONLY
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM SomeTable
   WHERE Something IN (SELECT * FROM @statusValue)
END
GO
```

--EDIT---

If you are using SSMS, you can execute the procedure as follows:

```
DECLARE @status dbo.StatusList
INSERT INTO @status VALUES('Pending')

EXEC [Report] @status
```

Comment: And how can I call my procedure with multiple parameters? What is it delimited by?

Comment: How do you call the procedure? via SSMS or some code?

Answer (score 0):

You need the split function in this case. As there is no way to handle what you need. Another approach to add many variables. But in your case it will be enough to create split function and use it to parse your string. Please find the split function below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufnSplitInlineStringToParameters] (
    @list NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,@delim NCHAR(1) = ','
    )
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
WITH csvTbl(START, STOP) AS (
        SELECT START = CONVERT(BIGINT, 1)
            ,STOP = CHARINDEX(@delim, @list + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @delim))

        UNION ALL

        SELECT START = STOP + 1
            ,STOP = CHARINDEX(@delim, @list + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @delim), STOP + 1)
        FROM csvTbl
        WHERE STOP > 0
        )

SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000), SUBSTRING(@list, START, CASE 
                        WHEN STOP > 0
                            THEN STOP - START
                        ELSE 0
                        END)))) AS VALUE
FROM csvTbl
WHERE STOP > 0

GO
```